# SharePoint Survey list when more tha 5000 response

Tags: sharepoint

I had created a survey in SharePoint 2010 Standard, we got the response from around 7k users.

the problem now is, It not able to show the result in normal user view as it hit 5k limit. I would like try to index the Survey list, but this is not possible as I don't see the option in survey list.

I tried to create new custom view, but my column is not something we can group easily with information.

Thus, is there anyway I can show the result? as of now, only admin can read the result.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is an on premises SharePoint installation, you (or a server administrator) can use Powershell to temporarily disable throttling on the list long enough to export the results to Excel. Once that's done, you can keep the results in Excel or you can re-import the items into a normal SharePoint list with column indexing to circumvent the threshold.

1. Log in to one of the web servers in the farm.
2. Start the "SharePoint 2010 Management Shell" (or else start the Powershell console and load the SharePoint management snap-ins)

Enter the following lines:

```
$web = get-spweb http://server.domain/site/web
$list = $web.Lists["List Title"]
$list.EnableThrottling = $false
$web.Dispose()
```

After you've exported the list to Excel, you'll want to turn throttling back on:

```
$web = get-spweb http://server.domain/site/web
$list = $web.Lists["List Title"]
$list.EnableThrottling = $true
$web.Dispose()
```

Remember to replace `http://server.domain/site/web` with the path to the site on which the list resides, and replace `List Title` with the actual name of the list.